# Need help sorting ListView items by date for Order History

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

This is how the Order History looks like:

[image: This is how the Order History looks like.]

What I want to do is sort the items in this `ListView` by Date.

So far, I can't find any useful resource materials where I can sort the items by date.

```
Private Sub frmOrderHistory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim orders As String = WindowsApplication1.Class1.Orders
    Dim arrCheck(3) As String
    Dim lineNum As Integer = -1
    For Each i As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(orders)
        Dim a, c As String
        a = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(i)
        c = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(i)
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(c)
            lineNum = lineNum + 1
            ListView1.Items.Add(a)
            arrCheck = Split(line, ",")
            ListView1.Items(lineNum).SubItems.Add(arrCheck(0))
            ListView1.Items(lineNum).SubItems.Add(arrCheck(1))
        Next

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You should bind the listview with the sorted data only. Or you want to do sorting inside the listview based on the header of  the column?

Comment: Please add your code how the ListView is populated.

Comment: @AlexB. I have added the requested code, thanks.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I would like the data to be sorted before being displayed.

Comment: Then you need to have the data sorted before you bind it to the listview. Answer posted by Brasdax should help you. Is there anything else which you are looking for.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The answer Brasdax has posted is in C#, my code is in Vb.net

Comment: That's a funniest excuse. Why don't you try to see what equivalent of C# is available in VB.NET ? It's all about calling proper methods on your collection? isnt' it? Did you try to see if there is method like OrderByDescending in VB.NET ? Did you try to search for it on google? Please do that...

Comment: Is this Winforms?  That ListView is a bad choice for DB Data because it doesnt do data binding and it only ever holds strings

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya This is for my college project which doesn't accept C#, I would do it in C# if I was allowed to. And yes I did try to search it on google, returning futile results.

Comment: Before I provide the solution let me know if below assumptions are correct. You have multiple order files which have their names in date format. And each file has multiple order items and each item is comma separated string of item name and price. Is that right?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes that is right.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to create list of objects which you want to display in the list view, sort the listview as per the requirement and then use the sorted list to the display in the list view.

I suggest to create a class `Order` to collect the order details from the file. Create list of orders and sort the list and then display it in the list view as following.

Following is the class `Order`.

```
Public Class Order
Public Property OrderDate() As DateTime
Get
    Return m_OrderDate
End Get
Set
    m_OrderDate = Value
End Set
    End Property
Private m_OrderDate As DateTime

Public Property Item() As String
Get
    Return m_Item
End Get
Set
    m_Item = Value
End Set
End Property
Private m_Item As String

Public Property Price() As Double
Get
    Return m_Price
End Get
Set
    m_Price = Value
End Set
End Property
Private m_Price As Double
End Class
```

Following is the code of list binding.

```
Private Sub frmOrderHistory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim orders As String = WindowsApplication1.Class1.Orders
    Dim arrCheck(3) As String
    Dim orderList = New List(Of Order)()
For Each filePath As var In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(orders)
    Dim order = New Order()
    order.OrderDate = DateTime.ParseExact(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    For Each line As var In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    arrCheck = line.Split(New Char() {","C})
    order.Item = arrCheck(0)
    order.Price = Convert.ToDouble(arrCheck(1))
    orderList.Add(order)
        Next
Next

Dim sortedOrder = orderList.OrderByDescending(Function([or]) [or].OrderDate).ToList()

    For i As var = 0 To sortedOrder.Count - 1
        listView1.Items.Add(sortedOrder(i).OrderDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
        listView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(sortedOrder(i).Item)
        listView1.Items(i).SubItems.Add(sortedOrder(i).Price.ToString("00.00"))
    Next
End Sub
```

As you can observer this solution is not straight forward. It requires formatting of string to datetime and back to string. The same with double values. Also requires looping thru items more than once.

Simpler would be to use datagridview. It takes a few clicks to set columns and dataformats of columns if you use datagridview. And you can bind collection of orders directly to it without looping thru the collection as following.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = sortedOrder;
```